# Pronunciation of ‘-eru-’

Tags: pronunciation

I’ve just come across the word ‘glomerular’ and I’m genuinely irked by how difficult it is to pronounce the *eru* bit. It seems online that the *r* is omitted, turning it into more of a *yuh* sound.

Does anyone have any idea why this particular combination is so tricky?

Comment: I'm not convinced that anybody actually does drop the /r/ in *glomerular*. Are you sure that there's not a faint /r/ in there that you're just not hearing? Do you have any sound clips of people saying *glomehyular*?

Comment: The British pronunciation that comes up from Google when you search for the pronunciation of glomerular does seem to drop the _r_, so I do believe it happens sometimes. Although you are right—in most other available clips, there is an _r_ present, which still makes this word insanely tricky to pronounce.

Comment: You're right; it does. I wonder where Google got it from.  And how many British physicians pronounce it that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### You don't need to use a pronunciation with the tricky -RY-  /rj/ sequence: you can just use -R- instead

Words like *glomerular* with a stressed vowel sound followed by *-ru-* + a consonant letter + a vowel letter can generally be pronounced in two ways: with a -ry- /r.j/ cluster, or with -r- /r/ without any following "y" /j/ sound. (My transcriptions between slashes in this post use the symbols of the International Phonetic Alphabet for the relevant sounds.)

Many dictionaries indicate this variation, such as Merriam-Webster which gives the pronunciation of *[glomerular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glomerular)* as "glə-ˈmer-(y)ə-lər" (using parentheses to indicate that the "y" sound is optional). So it's fine to say "glom-MERRuh-ler": you don't need to say "glom-MERR-yuh-ler".

Other words like this: *querulous, ferrule.* Vowels other than E can come before the R, also, as in *virulent* or *purulent.* Here's a list of words that I've been able to find with this spelling pattern:

- spelled with "er(r)u": erudite, ferule, ferrule, glomerulus, puberulent, querulous, serrula(te), spherule, verrucose
- spelled with "uru": curule, neurula, purulent
- spelled with "or(r)u": corrugate, morula, rorulent, torulose
- spelled with "iru": spirula, virulent
- spelled with "arru": barrulet, garrulous, squarrulose

(and also derivatives of the above such as *serrulation, virulence* etc.).

Speakers aren't necessarily consistent, so some people have /rj/ in some of these words but not in others.

In non-rhotic accents, it seems that at least some of these words may have pronunciations where /r/ is vocalized, like syllable-final /r/ may be in other contexts, leaving intervocalic /j/.<sup>1</sup>

#### Possible reasons why it's tricky to pronounce /rj/

As for why you find it difficult to pronounce, there is a paper "Phonetics in phonology: The markedness of rhotic+palatal glide sequences in English", by Tracy A Hall which discusses the preference against /rj/ sequences in English. In most accents, they don't occur at the start of syllables. Hall says that it is physically awkward to produce this sequence of sounds with the tongue:

> The tongue tip articulation for coronal /r/ sounds also requires that the dorsum and blade be in a concave shape, as opposed to the convex tongue posture for the articulation of /j/. Consequently the articulation of /r/ and /j/ would require that the tongue tip plus concave tongue posture be altered to a blade plus convex posture in rapid succession.

(page 254, in *Folia Linguistica XXXVII/3-4*)

### Discussion of other possible alternatives to /rj/

In theory, there are many ways that a disfavored sequence /rj/ could be "repaired", such as deletion of /r/ or /j/ or change of one into another sound. Different languages select different options; for example, Italian regularly changed /rj/ in its inherited vocabulary to /j/.

In English, deletion of /j/ and retention of /r/ seems to be the most frequent and widespread repair (for speakers who don't tolerate /rj/; some do) for the class of words spelled with *-ru-,* but other repair strategies are normal for other categories of words, and also seem to be applied sometimes to words in this class.

#### 1. Replacing /rj/ with /j/

Just as word-final /r/ is regularly vocalized or lost in non-rhotic accents in words like *lumber* and *under,* compounds formed from  such words, like "lumberyard" or "underutilised", regularly have /j/ with no preceding consonantal /r/ sound.

Contrary to what I previously thought and wrote in earlier revisions of this answer, at least some non-compound words spelled with *-ru-* seem to also have /r/-less pronunciations in non-rhotic accents as a non-negligible alternative to pronunciations with /rj/ or /r/.

An example I found attested in dictionaries is *torulose* (adj.): per the OED, its pronunciation can be any of /ˈtɒruːləʊs/, /ˈtɒr(j)ʊləʊs/, /ˈtɔːjʊləʊs/; similarly, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/torulose) lists /ˈtɔːjʊləʊs/, /ˈtɒrjʊləʊs/, /ˈtɔːjʊləʊz/, /ˈtɒrjʊləʊz/. However, I have not found any other *-ru*-spelled words where this type of non-rhotic pronunciation is attested by dictionaries. Caveat: this word is extremely rare (Youglish furnishes no audio examples of "torulose"), so I don't know whether lexicographers transcriptions for it are actually based on what they hear or instead on their own intuitions or applications of rules.

Thank you Daniel Ninan for [leaving a clarifying comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/585963/pronunciation-of-eru/585967#comment1466348_585963) specifying that you heard this going on in the pronunciation that Google presents as its "British pronunciation" of *glomerular.* I am still doubtful about this source's accuracy, and suspect that Google may be displaying an algorithmically generated pronunciation that isn't necessarily used by real human speakers, but I'm not certain.

The transcription given is "glo·**muh**·yu·luh", which seems to agree with the (evidently artificially synthesized) audio in missing /r/ and using the vowel sound of *nurse* in the stressed syllable. (Google uses the transcription "uh" to represent this vowel sound, as shown by its transcriptions for British English of *nurse* "nuhs" or *nursing* "**nuh** suhng" [sic].)

I do think we'd need to see some change from the DRESS vowel /ɛ/ to make a pronunciation without /r/ viable in British English. The vowel /ɛ/ is "lax" or "short" and doesn't as a rule occur directly before other vowels or before the semivowels /w/, /j/; compare it to /ɒ/ which the dictionaries indicate is used in *torulose* only before a pronounced /r/.

The usual correspondences in non-rhotic accents for syllable-final *ar er ir or ur* in stressed syllables are /ɑː/ /ɜː/ /ɔː/ /ɜː/ /ɜː/.

The pronunciation in [the video that Peter Shor found](https://youtu.be/lhtj6KANer8?t=260) and linked to in a comment ("University Challenge S45E28 University of Liverpool vs University of Newcastle") is interesting, but I'm also not sure what exactly it shows us, since I hear multiple pronunciations there. I hear, in order, whispering that I can't make out clearly, the quiz contestant saying [gləˈmɛjələs]~[gləˈmeɪələs]" as the answer, and Jeremy Paxman  "[gləˈmɛrijəs] is correct". Since it is a quiz show, this isn't necessarily an everyday word for any of these speakers, and it seems possible to me that they might have tongue slips or misremember details of the shape of the word (I perceive Paxman's pronunciation to have no [l] before the final [əs], which doesn't seem explicable as a result of a regular sound change rather than some anomalous alteration of the word's pronunciation, although it might be that he pronounced [l] and I just can't hear it clearly).

I'm inclined to identify the vowel in the answerer's pronunciation with the  FACE phoneme, although I'm not confident in this since I'm an American English speaker.

#### 2. Replacing /rj/ with /ri/?

Words spelled with "ri", such as *pictorial,* **usually** show syllabic /ri/ if repaired from /rj/ (although a few historical /rj/ *-ri-* words such as *marriage* and *carriage* have deleted the /j/).

This is not a common replacement for /rj/ in words spelled with *-ru-.* However, searching through [Youglish](https://youglish.com/pronounce/virulent/english/uk?) for examples of British English pronunciations, I noticed that when /j/ is not deleted in *-ru-* words (which is rare), it often sounds to me indistinguishable from a short /i/, so potentially that could be another repair method some speakers use. Examples:

- the host corrects himself from /r/ to what sounds like /ri/ in *virulent*: "[Has Britain Become Less Tolerant? (BBC Big Questions)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsfdqxqMzNc&t=378s)"
- the pronunciation of *erudite* in [this video](https://youtu.be/sqqt1jH91oY?t=30)
- the pronunciation of *erudite* in this video: [Jane Austen and the Army](https://youtu.be/RwQjDqkEoYk?t=2015), *NationalArmyMuseumUK,* Rupert Willoughby.

Comment: This might also explain why /rj/ did not lead to gemination in West Germanic.

Comment: Also why people tend not to pronounce the first *r* in "February".

Comment: Is this particular to UK English?  I would be pretty surprised to see the y sound deleted from "virulent."

Comment: @Casey: Avoidance of /rj/ in favor of /r/ occurs in American English as well: it is indicated by the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virulent) and the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=virulent) entries for "virulent".

Comment: The vowel in the /r/-less pronunciation of *glomerulus* has to be the FACE vowel; the DRESS vowel cannot be followed by /j/.

Answer (score 7):

TLDR: Many British accents are non-rhotic; in these accents, /r/ is dropped before consonants. So one would think a non-rhotic speaker would have to drop either the /r/ or the y (/j/ in IPA).

The pronunciation of *glomerular* in British English is given as /ɡlɒˈmɛr(j)ʊlə/ by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/glomerular). If you pronounce the "u" as /ju/, this is a word where /r/ precedes a consonant, and therefore people with non-rhotic accents would be inclined to drop the /r/. In a non-rhotic accent, one would have to drop either the /r/, the /j/, or turn "rul" into two syllables. Online, most of the British speakers I've heard seem to drop the /j/ rather than the /r/. However, it seems that some drop the /r/. I believe this would be the natural pronunciation of a non-rhotic speaker who had learned the word through hearing the American pronunciation
/ɡloˈmɛrjʊlər/

There are very few words in English where /r/ precedes /ju/. Two of these are *garrulous* (identified by herisson in the other answer) and *virulent*. Lexico gives the pronunciations [/ˈɡar(j)ʊləs/](https://www.lexico.com/definition/garrulous) and
[/ˈvɪrjʊlənt/](https://www.lexico.com/definition/virulent). However, I suspect that most British English speakers pronounce *garrulous* the same way I've heard most Americans do, without the /j/. For *virulent*, most of the sound clips I've found from British speakers drop the /j/, despite the pronunciation in Lexico dictionary. And [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/virulent) gives /ˈvɪr.jə.lənt/ as the US pronunciation and /ˈvɪr.ə.lənt/ as the UK pronunciation.

In rhotic accents, like most Americans have, the /r/ would always be pronounced.

Comment: To me, "/r/ is dropped before consonants" is a mis-characterisation of the phenomenon. I would say something like "/r/ is dropped in the syllable coda". While I can imagine the /r/ disappearing in "glomerula" with the difficulty of getting my toungue round it, the /r/ is definitely there in my mental model in the same way that it is there in "carry" but not in "car".I do pronounce "garrulous" without the /j/, but "virulent" with it.

Comment: +1 Spot on. Quick check round the room here (UK), and nobody pronounces a /j/ in *virulent.* If it ever was very common, perhaps it's now limited mainly to older speakers.

Comment: @herisson: In a non-rhotic dialect, most people will not pronounce both the /r/ and the /j/ (something Americans have relatively little  trouble with). So they have to drop one. And, as pointed out in the comments, there is indeed a common word where most people drop the /r/ rather than the /j/: *February.*

Comment: @Colin: I suppose that it doesn't apply to all British speakers, but it seems to me that *'r' is automatically dropped before consonants and inserted before vowels (as in **idear of**)* is a very common variety of non-rhotism*.

Comment: @PeterShor: I don't agree. It's dropped before consonants _at a syllable boundary_. /rju/ is the only case where these descriptions will be different, but I believe they are different. The dropped /r/ almost always colours the preceding vowel - mostly appearing as a schwa off-glide -  but the vowel preceding the 'r' in these words (including _glomerula_) has no trace of this: it is unaffected by whether or not the yod is dropped.

Comment: @herisson: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhtj6KANer8) (University Challenge S45E28 on YouTube at 4:22) is a British pronunciation of /ɡloˈmɛjʊləs/ found in the wild. The OP is correct; this pronunciation really exists.

Answer (score 2):

That is one mouthful of a word pronounce. It's not just the '-eru-', it's that whole back end.

Whether it's /glə ˈmer ə lər/ or /glə ˈmer jə lər/, there's a lot of mouth movement going on.

For example there's the tongue twister
['rural juror'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yhu2vIBd68k) ([lyrics](http://www.songlyrics.com/30-rock/season-1-the-rural-juror-lyrics/)).

It turns out that the mouth movements when pronouncing a word are not a string of independent mouth actions. There's a lot of anticipation, preparation for a subsequent sound while a very different one is going on. For example, in the word

> [construe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/construe)

at the end of pronouncing 'con-' and just as you're about to pronounce '-str-', your mouth is already forming the lips in anticipation of pronouncing the '-ue'.

The sounds /r/ and /l/ are both [liquids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_consonant) but there's a lot of variation within that family. In a [rhotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English) accent like US English, the mouth positions of 'l' and 'r' are very different. In the word 'glomerular', you're bouncing back and forth between 'r' and 'l'.

Also, the vowels move all over the place. The 'e' is [front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) the 'u' is [back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_back_rounded_vowel) and the 'a' is [mid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel).

So there's a lot of mouth gymnastics going on. Add in the the semi-vowel 'y' before the 'u' and it's extra work.

Added to this is that the word is not particularly common and the pieces are combined in ways that are not common (/er u/ is not common and /(y)ul ar/ is not common either).

Which is all to say that '-eru-' all by itself is really pretty easy, but add in all the other things and it's understandably difficult.

Comment: Just another mini-question (I hope this is fine to do), but what makes _y_ a semi-vowel?

Comment: @DanielNinan That's probably a topic for a shelf of books, probably better asked at [linguistics.se]. Short answer: the 'y' in 'yes' is a semivowel because it is not a vowel the 'center of a syllable' and it is the least consonant of the consonants because it hardly has any closure in the vocal tract. For more, see the wiki article on semivowels (but the controversy doesn't end there).

Comment: What about "rural juror" is supposed to make it hard to pronounce? If the transition from /rə/ to /əɫ/ is supposed to be hard, well, perhaps, but it occurs only once in that phrase.

Comment: @RosieF: In Received Pronunciation, it's not supposed to be /rərəl ˈdʒərə/ but /ˈrʊərəl ˈdʒʊərə/.  And /ˈʊərə/ is hard enough already, which I think is why it is often pronounced /rərəl ˈdʒərə/ (which is indeed much easier).